# Hash and whirpool in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, hash, passwords, whirlpool

I have an app that posts login data and checks to see if the password matches one in my database. The passwords in my databse are stored using the hash, whirlpool function.  How can I use hash, whirpool a password in ios obj-c?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [reference implementation](http://www.larc.usp.br/~pbarreto/WhirlpoolPage.html) in C is available from the authors.

Comment: Usually a link-only answer is frowned on, but in this case, it's perfect.  Well done. :)

Comment: I'll look at it when I get home. Thanks.